# Vim boolean function

Tags: function, vim, boolean

I am trying to implement a boolean function in Vim and having some trouble and I am sure there is something I'm missing.

Just to be clear, I'm looking to implement a function that when called with `!` it will do the opposite.

Vim has plenty of boolean functions, like `list` and `paste`. In my case, if I have a function that say, opens a buffer, like:

```
:call MyFunction()
```

Then I would like this to close the buffer when is called with a `!`:

```
:call MyFunction()!
```

Not sure if this is even possible, and I am not looking to find out how to open or close a buffer, but the actual boolean implementation.

Edit:

It seems that this is way more feasible if we talk about a user-defined command, like:

```
:MyCommand action
```

That can also be called as:

```
:MyCommand action!
```

Comment: You're confusing: the optional bang gets after the Command name: `:MyCommand! action`. See `:help :command` and `:help :command-bang`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating your command, give it the `-bang` option and then use the `<bang>`, which will expand to a bang or nothing. Then, to redirect this to your function create a special argument and analyze it to see whether it contains a bang or not. Something like this: (including what ZyX suggested)

```
function! Bang(bang)
    echo "With".((a:bang)?"":"out")." bang."
endfunction

command! -bang Bg call Bang(<bang>0)
```

Of course, I'm not doing the correct tests here to check if `a:bang` is really a bang, but you got the idea.

```
:Bg
Without bang.
```

```
:Bg!
With bang.
```

Comment: A neat trick is `<bang>0` in function arguments: this turns either to `0` without a bang or `1` with. Also instead of using `len(...)` in boolean context use `!empty(...)`.

Comment: Thanks ZyX! Really nice, I was looking for a better way to pass the argument. But is `empty()` really necessary here? Using a:bang value as condition seems to be enough.

Comment: I never said you should use `empty()` in *this* case. I just said that there is no need to use `len(...)` (and on strings it is much slower then `!empty(...)`).

Comment: Sorry @ZyX, I thought you were referring to use `empty()` with the new approach on passing the argument.